# Oracle regexp_replace optional group

Tags: regex, oracle, regexp-replace

I have a string 'SPECIFIC WORD BIG WORLD, SPECIFIC WORD BIG SUN'.
The output string should look like this: 'SPECIFIC WORD, SPECIFIC WORD'. In other words, I want to remove everything after 'SPECIFIC WORD' but I want to preserve commas. What I tried so far:

```
 declare
 l_string varchar2(10000);
 begin
    l_string := 'SPECIFIC WORD BIG WORLD, 
    SPECIFIC WORD BIG SUN, 
    SPECIFIC WORD BIG EARTH';
    dbms_output.put_line(l_string);
    l_string := regexp_replace(l_string, '(SPECIFIC WORD) (BIG)(.*)(,)?', '\1\4');
    dbms_output.put_line(l_string);
 end;
 /
```

The problem I have is that at the last match, there will be no comma but when I mark this comma as an optional sequence, I get no commas at all. Is there any way around this? I also tried to fix this playing with: 
https://regex101.com/
but I could not make optional comma behaving as a separate group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've described, following should suffice

```
l_string := regexp_replace(l_string, ' BIG \w+', '');
```

This just searches for

- a space
- followed by BIG
- followed by a space
- followed by a Word
  character, one to unlimited times

Comment: You were overthinking it. A fresh pair of eyes helps for that ;). If this answers your question, you can mark it as such.

Comment: Oh yes I forgot to do that sorry. Done! And thanks once again!